# No internet on Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, wireless, 20.04

I recently installed an Ubuntu Server in my Laptop (natively, not in a virtual machine). Everything worked fine until I used apt update - it didn't work. Quick diagnosis, and it was clear I simply didn't have an internet connection - WiFi is not working. I do not have any form of wired communication at my disposal, so I am doomed to a wireless connection. This is not a hardware problem - Linux Mint is on the same machine and has no connection problems. So I searched the internet for a solution to the problem - it's fairly simple, but it has one catch: all ways to connect via WiFi require you to install Wirelles Tools. However, I cannot do it in a conventional way, of course due to the fact that the system is Offline all the time. How can I install Wirelles Tools differently, e.g. from a Pendrive?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Linux Mint. Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wireless-tools&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all and download `wireless-tools`.

You will also need `wpasupplicant` found at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wpasupplicant&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all.

Put the .deb files on a flash drive.

Boot to Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. Install the .deb file with `sudo dpkg -i /path_to/wireless-tools_30~pre9-13ubuntu1_amd64.deb`. Use the correct .deb filename. Same for `wpasupplicant`.

Then do `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and edit that output into your question.

Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Then I'll give you the next step.